# Inheriting 'Class' properties in Backbone

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js

I am trying to determine how it may be possible to inherit "class" properties of Backbone objects. Class properties are explained here:
https://taurenmills.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/backbone-js-with-class-properties/

We can do inheritance with Backbone, like so:

```
var BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

   someFunc1: function(){

   },

   someFunc2: function(){

   }

 },
 {   //class properties below

 newInstance: function(attrs,opts_{
    var model = new BaseModel(attrs);
    model.randomProp = opts.randomProp;
    return model;
 }

});



var SubModel = BaseModel.extend({

   someFunc2: function(){  //overrides someFunc2 in BaseModel
      someFunc1(); calls someFunc1 in BaseModel
   }
 },

{  //class properties below

   newInstance: function(attrs,opts){
      var model = new SubModel (attrs);
      model.randomProp = opts.randomProp;
      return model;
   }

}
);
```

my question is: how can we inherit the "class" functions from BaseModel?
I would like for my subclasses of BaseModel to inherit the class function `newInstance`.

But I don't think that's possible. Coming from Java, it's not straightforward as how to inherit static methods which refer to the subclass itself in the inherited static method, not the superclass.

ignoring what I just said, in other words, I would like to do something like:

```
newInstance: function(attrs,opts){
    var Constr = this.constructor; //*but* the 'this' keyword will not be available in the newInstance function, which is like a static method in Java
    var model = new Constr(attrs);
    model.randomProp = opts.randomProp;
    return model;
 }
```

the reason I want to implement the class function is so that I can set a specific property on the new model instance everytime that function is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You can access method from your base *class* by using your object's prototype.

For example if you wanted to call your base classes initialize method you would do the following

```
  //base class
   initialize: function (attributes, options) {
       this.someProperty = options.somePropery
    },

   //sub class
   initialize: function (attributes, options) {
        BaseModel.prototype.initialize.call(this,attributes, options);
    },
```

That said, inheritance really works a bit differently in JavaScript (this isn't really unique to backbone) to how it works in Java and you probably should read up a bit on the object prototype.

Comment: thanks Jack, yeah I was more referring to how inheritance of "static"/class methods might work in JavaScript. These static methods do get inherited in Java somehow but I am not sure about JS.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your trying to do, but as I pointed out in my answer you do have access to the parent's methods in your *inherited*/child class. If you weren't implementing/overriding a method with the same name you would be able to call it in the child class without using the prototype.

Comment: I can't do what I want to do, and I couldn't do it in Java either. Want I want to do is to share a static/class method in the BaseModel with all the SubModel instances. But the problem is that I need a reference to the SubModel classes in the BaseModel static method, and that is impossible, or just poor design. It's hard to explain. But I am sure of it. I just created a factory method that is independent of the model classes. I can show you an example in Java if you are interested in why this doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps it might be a good idea to take a step back, what are you trying to do? Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ribizotitu/edit?js,console,output) that maybe better shows how you can accomplish what it sounds like your asking. If you think a Java example would better illustrate what you want to do you can post that.